# Can't find library png++

Tags: c++, eclipse, image

I'm trying to use the png++ library. Already added it to the library search path in eclipse (windows user, if relevant), but I get the

```
fatal error: png++/png.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I really don't know what to do. 
Thank you!

Comment: Make sure your path is accessible without administrator privileges. Also make sure the directory you have included "png++" folder inside it

Comment: The path is accessible, and the directory have the file "png.hpp". I have changed the include to
    #include <png++-0.2.9\png.hpp>
but didn't work either.

Comment: If the directory name is png++-0.2.9  and png.hpp and all other header files are under it, then change that to png++. And add "parent directory" of "png++" to the project properties in Eclipse. Then it should work.

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried including the path to C/C++ Build>Settings>GCC C compiler, the path of the parent directory and the png.hpp in the include files. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot write all details in comment, so I'm adding an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days, tears and blood, my professor (PhD Daniel Brake) figured it out! Here is what we did to make it work. I hope you never need to use this library on a Windows machine (conf: Windows 10, MinGW, Eclipse):

- Make sure that you have the MinGW installation manager, have all the packages on the basic setup installed, and in "all packages", look for "msys-zlib", class dll
- Now open the cmd (Windows+x, A, to open in admin mode)
- You have to open the "msys.bat", go to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat`
- It will open a unix-like terminal, then type:

  - `mingw-get install libz-dev`
  - `cd /path/to/libpng/folder`
  - `./configure -prefix=/mingw`
  - `make`
  - `make install`
- Google png++, download it, and using the MinGW terminal go to the folder that contains it:

  - `cd /path/to/png++/folder`
  - `tar -zxf png++-0.2.x.tar.gz -C`
- In the png++ page, go to http://savannah.nongnu.org/bugs/?46312 and donwnload the file to the png++ folder
- Replace the error.hpp file
- Using a text editor, open the error.hpp file you just downloaded
- Add `#include <sstream>` to the includes
- look for the part and comment it:

  `strerror_r(errnum, buf, ERRBUF_SIZE);
          return std::string(buf);`
- Now, add this in the same block of above:
  `std::stringstream ss;
   ss << errnum;
   return ss.str();`
- Save and close
- Now, open Eclipse, create the project for the png++
- Go to Configuration > C/C++ Build > set Configuration to "Debug [Active]"
- Then C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC C++ compiler, add to "Include paths (-l)", the path to the folder png++ and the path to the folder that contains the file `png.h`, in my case it's in "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\mingw\include"
- Go to MinGW C++ Linker > Libraries, add to "Libraries (-l)" just the word "png" and in the "Library seach path (-L)" the path to the folder of libpng.a, in my case, "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\mingw\lib"
- save
- to use it, in the header, add `#include <png.hpp>` (not `#include <png++/png.hpp>`)
- it will have a warning, you can ignore it
- it doesn't works!
- in your MinGW terminal, go to the folder that have the "eclipse.exe" and open the Eclipse that way (don't ask me, my professor said something about path, I have no idea why)
  Maybe you can simply use another compiler, but I couldn't, or use Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. You need to check your settings one by one.

- It (png++) is a C++ library, so you must have C++ compiler set in your
  run/debug settings.
- Add your library include folder to that compiler's settings
- To actually link to the library, you need to add the .lib/.a files or DLLs to linker settings.

I'm not much of a user of Eclipse CDT but that's how it works. If you are trying to do image manipulation without prior C++ experience, I suggest you to go with python/Java, they are easy to use.